# PhpStorm & PHPUnit: launch tests by mouse click

Tags: ide, phpunit, phpstorm

How I can setup IDEA PhpStorm to launch PHPUnit tests (classes or even methods) using context menu (right button click of the mouse)? I have 2 composer modules  in my project, one of them allows to launch tests with right button click, but other one does not (as 'PHP Script' only option available).

[image]